# How to add custom tab to youtube channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-channels

Want to add the custom tab to youtube channel. Can somebody send me the steps for this. As I searched for it, but not found any proper solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Custom tabs are now a form of gadgets. Check out this [link](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1727240?hl=en) for more information about the guidelines when creating a gadget. Typically you need to have invested a minimum amount in advertising to be approved by Google. If you have contact with a Google representative for your channel, it's worth asking them. It's not an option available to everyone.

Comment: It's just html development user guide that is going to be embedded in iframe. How can I reach to Google representative?